# Can I use a pandas udf on a pyspark-dataframe after I used a normal (scalar) udf to clean it?

Tags: pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, rdd

I have seen "gotchyas" and other issues with mixing Vectorized and non-Vectorized UDFs on a pyspark dataframe, and want to understand the correct general approach going forward.

Due to issues with differences between 'None' in pyspark and nan in  pandas, I used a normal (non-vectorized) udf to clean up a column of lists in a pyspark dataframe. After cleaning, I aim to use vectorized or pandas UDFs to scale and normalize data, but run into an error:

```
IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/content/spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     78             if s.startswith('java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '):
---> 79                 raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     80             raise
     81     return deco

IllegalArgumentException: 'Can not mix vectorized and non-vectorized UDFs'
```

This simple pandas udf that triggerred this was:

```
@pandas_udf(ArrayType(LongType()))
def func(v):
    return pd.Series(v)
```

which works on a small example dataframe that I did not use any UDFs (scalar or otherwise).

My functioning work-around is to convert to  rdd and back to DF, and I believe this is not nice, clean, smart, or scalable! It does work though. Should the normal approach be to use all the UDFs on a dataframe, send to through the RDD wash cycle, and then use Pandas UDFs? What's a better way to deal with udf "mixing"?